# Apps won't install or update after I cleared files and data

Tags: applications, stock-android

My phone is a mess right now. I cleared some files and data. Now, my Play Store stopped functioning. All my apps won't give notifications anymore. What should I do to fix this huge problem? I just uninstalled all the apps, and they won't let me install or update them again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a factory reset? In my Samsung Galaxy S4, it's in: `System settings > Acceounts > Backup and reset > Factory data reset`. See if you can find something similar to your phone.

**WARNING:** You will lose all your data when you do a factory reset. But since you uninstalled all your apps, it shouldn't be any problem / issue.